# Saving / Creating data to associated table is not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have three table,

> Authors
>
> Stories
>
> Details

Stories and Details are associated with the Authors, with **hasOne** relationship.

Bellow is the code in my AuthorsController

```
function add(){
   if($this->request->is('POST')){
     $author = $this->Authors->newEntity($this->request->data,
           ['associated' => ['Stories', 'Details'], 'validate' => false]
     );
     $this->Authors->save($author);
  }
}
```

This is only saving data in the Authors table, not in the other two table.
Bellow is the data I have in $this->request->data

```
'Authors' => [
    'name' => 'Bikash'
    'Age' => '22'
    'stories' => [
        'name' => 'Life Without the L'
        'gener_id' => 5
    ]
    'details' => [
         'qualification' => 'XYZ'
         'biography'
     ]

  ];
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Please share the model table as well, where you have defined the associations

Comment: **$this-Authors->save($authors, ['associated' => ['Stories', 'Details'])**  https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations

Comment: What is the association the other way. Stories and Details are associated with the Authors, with hasOne relationship but what is the Relationship of Authors to stories and details? Is it a hasMany or a hasOne also. If it is a hasMany the story and detail relations _should_ be a belongs to instead of a hasOne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong property names, `stories` and `details` won't work.

The default association property name for `hasOne` associations, is the underscored *singular* variant of the association alias, so for `Stories` that would `story`, and for `Details` it would be `detail`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > HasOne Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)**
- **[Inflector Sandbox > Stories](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/inflector?string=Stories)**
- **[Inflector Sandbox > Details](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/inflector?string=Details)**